# NullPointException upload file in Struts 2

Tags: file-upload, configuration, struts2, struts2-interceptors, interceptorstack

I'm trying to upload a file using forms and i'm following a tutorial found on internet. With this code I receive a `NullPointerException`.

This is the index.jsp:

```xml
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label for="myFile">Upload your file</label>
    <input type="file" name="myFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
   </form>
    </body>
```

This is success.jsp (in case of upload success):

```xml
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Success</title>
</head>
<body>
  You have successfully uploaded <s:property value="myFileFileName"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The Action class:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import java.io.IOException; 

    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

    public class uploadFile extends ActionSupport{
    private File myFile;
    private String myFileContentType;
    private String myFileFileName;
    private String destPath;

      public String execute()
   {
                    /* Copy file to a safe location */
               destPath = "C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/work/";

      try{
         System.out.println("Src File name: " + myFile);
         System.out.println("Dst File name: " + myFileFileName);

         File destFile  = new File(destPath, myFileFileName);
         FileUtils.copyFile(myFile, destFile);

      }catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         return ERROR;
      }

      return SUCCESS;
   }
        public File getMyFile() {
        return myFile;
    } 
        public void setMyFile(File myFile) {
         this.myFile = myFile;
   }
   public String getMyFileContentType() {
      return myFileContentType;
   }
   public void setMyFileContentType(String myFileContentType) {
      this.myFileContentType = myFileContentType;
   }
   public String getMyFileFileName() {
      return myFileFileName;
   }
   public void setMyFileFileName(String myFileFileName) {
      this.myFileFileName = myFileFileName;
   }
}
```

Struts.xmf configuration file:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />

   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
     <action name="upload" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.uploadFile">
       <interceptor-ref name="basicStack">
       </interceptor-ref>
       <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
           <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif</param>
       </interceptor-ref>
       <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
       <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
   </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Note: `error.jsp` is equivalent to `success.jsp`, only different message is print in the body.

Comment: Post a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileUpload` Interceptor must run before the `BasicStack` Interceptor Stack.

Change this

```xml
<action name="upload" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.uploadFile">
   <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
   <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
       <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
```

to this

```xml
<action name="upload" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.uploadFile">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
```